# How was Ego born?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2, celestials

In *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2*,

> Ego seems to describe his origin as simply realizing that he was alive, and then discovering that he could attain immortality through his relationship with a planet that it sounds like he discovered. So there was a period in which Ego existed before he even discovered the planet. There was no mention of his parents or even of other-universe relations, like a brother Alter Ego. It just seems as if Ego has always been alone, except for using beings in his project. There is even the idea that Ego himself decided that he was a Celestial based on how people he met described Celestials. Even though his own power seems to be a result of a planet that he discovered.

**So, in the MCU, how was Ego created?**

Comment: Why the down vote? Drax asked Ego how Peter was created. Ego answered that he made a tool appropriate for the task.

Comment: He created that planet, not discovered it.

Comment: Using an out-of-universe example, I found some parallelisms with the concept and hypotesis of "Boltzmann brain", the random apparition of a self-aware being from fluctuations out of the cosmic chaos.

Comment: Random alterations over billions of years, just like humans

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the -616 universe, Ego has a definite origin: he was created by another cosmic being, The Stranger. The same being created Alter-Ego, and the moon Id.

However, the -616 cosmology is incredibly complex and, frankly, a jumbled mess. So, in the MCU, so far as we know, much of it doesn't exist. Instead, Ego was a cosmic-level entity that simply came into being, naturally and from nothingness. He simply "evolved" from whatever stuff exists in deep space (cosmic energy of some sort, perhaps -- it's never clearly explained) into what he is.

As such, Ego does not have "parents", or indeed is he even a member of a race of beings. He just *is*: a sentient thing that arose out of the void of space on his own. As he grew he gained intelligence, until he began to "figure out" things like how to *make* a planet, and how to create humanoid avatars of himself, etc. The planet is not something he discovered in space; it is his own form, which grew bigger as he expanded his consciousness. Every bit of the planet *and* every one of those saplings *and* every part of the humanoid character that talks to Peter *is* Ego.

Comment: Ego describes becoming one with the planet. Much as he describes how the seeds that he planted on planets all over the Galaxy will enable him to consume the other planets in the Galaxy. Therefore the planets are like food that he consumes to make himself bigger. It does not seem that he is the planet as much as it seems that he ate the planet. ... This meshes with your image of Ego being Cosmic consciousness.

Comment: I saw the movie again tonight. Ego formed the planet from cosmic stuff. He did not eat it. He created it as a form for himself. This meshes with your answer so I am marking yours accepted.

Answer (score 2):

The official book, [*Marvel Studios’ The Marvel Cinematic Universe: An Official Timeline*](https://books.google.com/books/about/Marvel_Studios_the_Marvel_Cinematic_Univ.html?id=aeqSzwEACAAJ), reveals that Ego came into being by happenstance. He started as a lonely spark of consciousness drifting in deep space.

[image: The Marvel Cinematic Universe: An Official Timeline description of Ego]

> ##### Dawn of the Universe | Ego Takes Shape
>
> Not all Celestials are born from the cores of planets. Some evolve seemingly by happenstance, like the Celestial known as Ego. At first just a spark of consciousness alone in deep space, Ego manipulates matter to construct physical neural-networks for itself in a large, brain-like receptacle, then assembles an entire planet layer by layer around that. While other Celestials exist in the form of colossal giants, Ego prefers to mimic more humble forms of life, creating avatars that look like "lesser" sentient creatures found on distant worlds.